# Span of linear dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $\{v_1 \ldots v_n \}$ be a linear dependent set of vectors from a vector space $V$. We can show then that:

$$ v_j = span\{v_1 \ldots v_{j-1}, v_{j+1}, \ldots v_n \} $$

Because since it is linearly dependent, we can always choose a non-null (all together) set of elements $x_i$ of a field $\mathbf{F}$ such that:

$$ v_j = - \frac{\sum_{i\neq j}^{n} x_i v_i}{x_j}$$

Yet I have to prove a corollary which states that under the same conditions:

$$ span(v_1 \ldots v_n) = span(v_1 \ldots v_{j-1}, v_{j+1}, ,\ldots v_n) $$

and I am stuck because my results show that they are not the same. Any tips or advices to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: How is it that a vector ($v_j$) is equal to a set of vectors (the span on the right-hand side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume $j=n$. Let $X=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $Y=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$. It is easy to see that
$$
X\geq Y
$$from the definition of the spanned subspace. Now, to prove that
$$
X\leq Y,
$$ it is sufficient to show that
$$
\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n}\}\subset Y.
$$ But this is obvious from the fact that $x_n\in Y$ and $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\}\subset Y$.

Comment: Thank you!  It has surely helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same:

- since $\{v_1,\ldots v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n\}\subset\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$,$$\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n\}\bigr)\subset\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\bigr);$$
- each element of $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a linear combination of elements of $\{v_1,\ldots v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n\}$,$$\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n\}\bigr)\supset\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\bigr).$$